# sending multiple http requests on input change and apply the last change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http

I am using angularjs. I am sending a get request every time an input changes. And when I got the result the UI changes accordingly. However, my problem is that the user may enter input quickly and for some reasons (internet delay maybe) the last HTTP call finishes before the others and the UI will display the changes of the last FINISHED call, not the last called request. My question is, is there a way to make sure the last api called is the one gets applied?

Code example:

html:

```
<input type=" ng-change="$ctrl.reloadData()"
                             />
```

js:

```
function reloadData(){
     $http.get("/myurl").then(function(data){
         //update ui with data
     })
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One approach is to chain off the previous re-load:

```
promise = $q.when();
function reloadData(){
     promise = promise.then(function() {
         return $http.get("/myurl").then(function(data){
         //update ui with data
     });
};
```

Also one can use `ng-model-options` to throttle the number of calls:

```
<input ng-model="input1"
       ng-change="$ctrl.reloadData()"
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `ng-model-options` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend not sending a GET request every time the input changes, this will send a lot of unused requests.

You can use a timeout function to limit the amount of GET requests being send. Angular http has a method called `unsubscribe`, which you can use to unsubscribe from the request like this:

```
var timeout = null;
var request = null;

function reloadData() {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    if (request) request.unsubscribe();

    timeout = setTimeout(_ => {
        request = $http.get("/myurl").then(function(data){
            //update ui with data
        });
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: The AngularJS [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage) returns promises and does not have an `.unsubscribe` method.